# Is there a way to run Netflix under a 32bit computer?

Tags: 14.04, netflix

Now that Google Chrome is not giving any support for 32bit Ubuntu computers I'm having issues to watch programs in my old HP Pavilion with Ubuntu 14.04. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but if you are using an old 32 bit PC (as I am) the performance is not good.  You have to go back to the way we did it prior to the native Chrome solution, namely [pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html).

Detailed instructions are available at the link, but to sum up:

1. You add the pipelight ppa and install pipelight. (this installs a customized version of wine)
2. You enable the silverlight plugin
3. You install a browser agent switcher to fool Netflix into thinking
   you are running on a supported system.

I have done it, and it works, but I am not happy with it.  I seek a better solution.